# MySQL - Incorrect string value error

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

In mysql When saving some 3-byte character like : `'⁜'` (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205c/index.htm)

I get an mysql error:

> incorrect string value : 'xE2\x81\x9C....for column'

I tried in different mysql environments and locally the operation succeeds but in a prod environment it throws an error...
I tried checking charsets and collation settings in both and tried to reproduce the error in my local env without success.

I need help figuring out what is the problem and how to reproduct it.

Comment: What is the OS of the local env en of the prod env?

Comment: both are linux based. locally i run ubuntu, in prod i dont know exactly what linux dist it is running.

Comment: What I would do now is diff the configuration of both dbs, especially unicode handling and version of the engings etc. There must be a difference somewhere, but I cannot not see them now of course

Comment: Java? PHP? Perl?  VB?  Please show us the client code and the connection parameters.  It sounds like utf8 was not specified somewhere.

Comment: I tried to create the same database with the generated create statements but could not get the same error. I checked the charsets and collation in both environments and the database charset in prod is latin1. In the relevant  table it's is utf8 (charset) and ut8_unicode_ci (collation) and both use the MyISAM version 10 mysql engine. The backend code uses php with propel ORM.